# I want to display the content of a text field only if it has been entered

Tags: plugin-development, custom-field

I need a little help with my very first plugin. It's not that big a plugin and consists of a small settings page with 3 text fields that display on the woocommerce checkout page with some css.

I'm stuck at one bit though. I want to display the fields only if they have something to display. At the moment when they're empty, it will display the background css styling and still behave on click. I just want to have it not display if the field is empty.

In the public folder of the plugin I've got this. I hope someone can shed some light on it for me

```
// first button below billing form
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'show_my_message');
    function show_my_message() {

    $wc_checkout_message_settings = get_option('wc_checkout_message_settings');

        echo $wc_checkout_message_settings[wc_checkout_message_text_field_0];

        echo '<br>';

        echo $wc_checkout_message_settings[wc_checkout_message_text_field_1];

} 
// second set of buttons linking to payment only section
add_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'show_new_message');
    function show_new_message(){

    $wc_checkout_message_settings = get_option('wc_checkout_message_settings');

    echo $wc_checkout_message_settings[wc_checkout_message_text_field_2];

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do **echo** inside an if statement.

```
function show_my_message() {
  $settings = get_option('wc_checkout_message_settings');

  //Check if the array is set
  if( isset($settings['wc_checkout_message_text_field_0']) && !empty($settings['wc_checkout_message_text_field_0']) ){
    echo $settings['wc_checkout_message_text_field_0'];   
  } 

  //Check the other value and show it
  if(isset($settings['wc_checkout_message_text_field_1']) && !empty($settings['wc_checkout_message_text_field_1']) ){
    echo $settings['wc_checkout_message_text_field_1']; 
  }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. When I test it on my staging site I now get a 500 error

Comment: I just figured it out. There's a barcket ) missing at the end of the if line, but when I fixed that I'm still seeing the css. Would it be because I'm using a text field and have previously entered something there? I deleted the content and clicked save and it's empty, so I'd assume it shouldn't show anything

Comment: @JohnCook Try my updated answer, you should also check if the value is not empty. Since `get_option` will return false when the key is not exists, the `isset` conditionals will always true.

Comment: You're missing quotes around the array indexes...

Comment: @JacobPeattie I picked that up too. I'm going to mark this as the correct answer as it's now working perfectly. I knew it has to be an if statement, but wasn't exactly sure how to do it. I'm glad I asked. I'm a bit excited doing my first plugin and I hope it all works in the end